# How should I parse mysqldump binary output

Tags: python, mysql, binary-data

```
INSERT INTO `mytable` VALUES ('\0\0^\ft^^f~hr°Ù3^Y','column2',1);
```

is a part of mysqldump of a table. 
I know there is a `--hex-blob` option, but how do I parse the first column as `00001C66741E667E6872B0D933199292`

This is essentially language-agnostic, but if a python-based solution exists, it'd be great.